# rake db:migrate gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, redmine

I have spent the last week trying to set up the following config:
VPS with clean Centos 7 install.
Ruby on Rails which runs Redmine, all to read out a back-up of the redmine database made with bacula.

Now mind you, I come from a Graphical design/Microsoft/Hardware engineering background and am now currently transitioning so I'm still very unfamiliar with most of the stack used at my current employer as I have only been working there for a couple of weeks.

Setting up the VPS and installing Centos7 is easy enough, I then proceed with installing rbenv/httpd/bundler/rmagick/all the gems and restore the redmine back-up (back-up from the entire install).

Now I want to run a rake db:migrate command (just following the wiki's from redmine and digital ocean) and this happens:

```
[user@machinename redmine]$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[user@machinename redmine]$
```

If I then inspect lets say 00-core_plugins.rb I can't seem to find what is wrong.

```
# Loads the core plugins located in lib/plugins
Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, "lib/plugins/*")).sort.each do |directory|
  if File.directory?(directory)
    lib = File.join(directory, "lib")
    if File.directory?(lib)
      $:.unshift lib
      ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths += [lib]
    end
    initializer = File.join(directory, "init.rb")
    if File.file?(initializer)
      config = RedmineApp::Application.config
      eval(File.read(initializer), binding, initializer)
    end
  end
end
```

If anyone could offer some help/insight to what it is I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.
A standalone installer which sets up redmine and all dependencies is also good as I actually only have to be able to import the back-up of the DB in to redmine.

Full --trace:

```
[user@machinename redmine]$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Database.yml:

```
# Default setup is given for MySQL with ruby1.9.
# Examples for PostgreSQL, SQLite3 and SQL Server can be found at the end.
# Line indentation must be 2 spaces (no tabs).

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: redmine
  password: "therightpassword_icheckeditadozentimes"
  encoding: utf8

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: redmine
  password: "therightpassword_icheckeditadozentimes"
  encoding: utf8

# PostgreSQL configuration example
#production:
#  adapter: postgresql
#  database: redmine
#  host: localhost
#  username: postgres
#  password: "postgres"

# SQLite3 configuration example
#production:
#  adapter: sqlite3
#  database: db/redmine.sqlite3

# SQL Server configuration example
#production:
#  adapter: sqlserver
#  database: redmine
#  host: localhost
#  username: jenkins
#  password: jenkins
```

Configuration.yml

```
# = Redmine configuration file
#
# Each environment has it's own configuration options.  If you are only
# running in production, only the production block needs to be configured.
# Environment specific configuration options override the default ones.
#
# Note that this file needs to be a valid YAML file.
# DO NOT USE TABS! Use 2 spaces instead of tabs for identation.

# default configuration options for all environments
  default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration
  # See the examples below and the Rails guide for more configuration options:
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      #ssl: true
      address: smtp.gmail.com
      port: "587"
      domain: "site.tld"
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "ticketing@site.tld"
      password: "god our security is atrocious"

  # ==== Simple SMTP server at localhost
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :smtp
  #    smtp_settings:
  #      address: "localhost"
  #      port: 25
  #
  # ==== SMTP server at example.com using LOGIN authentication and checking HELO for foo.com
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :smtp
  #    smtp_settings:
  #      address: "example.com"
  #      port: 25
  #      authentication: :login
  #      domain: 'foo.com'
  #      user_name: 'myaccount'
  #      password: 'password'
  #
  # ==== SMTP server at example.com using PLAIN authentication
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :smtp
  #    smtp_settings:
  configuration.yml #      address: "example.com"
  #      port: 25
  #      authentication: :plain
  #      domain: 'example.com'
  #      user_name: 'myaccount'
  #      password: 'password'
  #
  # ==== SMTP server at using TLS (GMail)
  # This might require some additional configuration. See the guides at:
  # http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :smtp
  #    smtp_settings:
  #      enable_starttls_auto: true
  #      address: "smtp.gmail.com"
  #      port: 587
  #      domain: "smtp.gmail.com" # 'your.domain.com' for GoogleApps
  #      authentication: :plain
  #      user_name: "your_email@gmail.com"
  #      password: "your_password"
  #
  # ==== Sendmail command
  #
  #  email_delivery:
  #    delivery_method: :sendmail

  # Absolute path to the directory where attachments are stored.
  # The default is the 'files' directory in your Redmine instance.
  # Your Redmine instance needs to have write permission on this
  # directory.
  # Examples:
  # attachments_storage_path: /var/redmine/files
  # attachments_storage_path: D:/redmine/files
   attachments_storage_path:

  # Configuration of the autologin cookie.
  # autologin_cookie_name: the name of the cookie (default: autologin)
  # autologin_cookie_path: the cookie path (default: /)
  # autologin_cookie_secure: true sets the cookie secure flag (default: false)
   autologin_cookie_name:
   autologin_cookie_path:
   autologin_cookie_secure:

  # Configuration of SCM executable command.
  #
  # Absolute path (e.g. /usr/local/bin/hg) or command name (e.g. hg.exe, bzr.exe)
  # On Windows + CRuby, *.cmd, *.bat (e.g. hg.cmd, bzr.bat) does not work.
  #
  # On Windows + JRuby 1.6.2, path which contains spaces does not work.
  # For example, "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe".
  # If you want to this feature, you need to install to the path which does not contains spaces.
  # For example, "C:\TortoiseHg\hg.exe".
  #
  # Examples:
  # scm_subversion_command: svn                                       # (default: svn)
  # scm_mercurial_command:  C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe        # (default: hg)
  # scm_git_command:        /usr/local/bin/git                        # (default: git)
  # scm_cvs_command:        cvs                                       # (default: cvs)
  # scm_bazaar_command:     bzr.exe                                   # (default: bzr)
  # scm_darcs_command:      darcs-1.0.9-i386-linux                    # (default: darcs)
  #
   scm_subversion_command:
   scm_mercurial_command:
   scm_git_command:
   scm_cvs_command:
   scm_bazaar_command:
   scm_darcs_command:

  # SCM paths validation.
  #
  # You can configure a regular expression for each SCM that will be used to
  # validate the path of new repositories (eg. path entered by users with the
  # "Manage repositories" permission and path returned by reposman.rb).
  # The regexp will be wrapped with \A \z, so it must match the whole path.
  # And the regexp is case sensitive.
  #
  # You can match the project identifier by using %project% in the regexp.
  #
  # You can also set a custom hint message for each SCM that will be displayed
  # on the repository form instead of the default one.
  #
  # Examples:
  # scm_subversion_path_regexp: file:///svnpath/[a-z0-9_]+
  # scm_subversion_path_info: SVN URL (eg. file:///svnpath/foo)
  #
  # scm_git_path_regexp: /gitpath/%project%(\.[a-z0-9_])?/
  #
   scm_subversion_path_regexp:
   scm_mercurial_path_regexp:
   scm_git_path_regexp:
   scm_cvs_path_regexp:
   scm_bazaar_path_regexp:
   scm_darcs_path_regexp:
   scm_filesystem_path_regexp:

  # Absolute path to the SCM commands errors (stderr) log file.
  # The default is to log in the 'log' directory of your Redmine instance.
  # Example:
  # scm_stderr_log_file: /var/log/redmine_scm_stderr.log
   scm_stderr_log_file:

  # Key used to encrypt sensitive data in the database (SCM and LDAP passwords).
  # If you don't want to enable data encryption, just leave it blank.
  # WARNING: losing/changing this key will make encrypted data unreadable.
  #
  # If you want to encrypt existing passwords in your database:
  # * set the cipher key here in your configuration file
  # * encrypt data using 'rake db:encrypt RAILS_ENV=production'
  #
  # If you have encrypted data and want to change this key, you have to:
  # * decrypt data using 'rake db:decrypt RAILS_ENV=production' first
  # * change the cipher key here in your configuration file
  # * encrypt data using 'rake db:encrypt RAILS_ENV=production'
   database_cipher_key:

  # Set this to false to disable plugins' assets mirroring on startup.
  # You can use `rake redmine:plugins:assets` to manually mirror assets
  # to public/plugin_assets when you install/upgrade a Redmine plugin.
  #
  #mirror_plugins_assets_on_startup: false

  # Your secret key for verifying cookie session data integrity. If you
  # change this key, all old sessions will become invalid! Make sure the
  # secret is at least 30 characters and all random, no regular words or
  # you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
  #
  # If you have a load-balancing Redmine cluster, you have to use the
  # same secret token on each machine.
  #secret_token: 'change it to a long random string'
   secret_token: 'rake output I generated before and copy-pasta'ed'

  # Requires users to re-enter their password for sensitive actions (editing
  # of account data, project memberships, application settings, user, group,
  # role, auth source management and project deletion). Disabled by default.
  # Timeout is set in minutes.
  #
  #sudo_mode: true
  #sudo_mode_timeout: 15

  # Absolute path (e.g. /usr/bin/convert, c:/im/convert.exe) to
  # the ImageMagick's `convert` binary. Used to generate attachment thumbnails.
  #imagemagick_convert_command:

  # Configuration of RMagcik font.
  #
  # Redmine uses RMagcik in order to export gantt png.
  # You don't need this setting if you don't install RMagcik.
  #
  # In CJK (Chinese, Japanese and Korean),
  # in order to show CJK characters correctly,
   pt/redmine-3.1.0/log/"
  # you need to set this configuration.
  #
  # Because there is no standard font across platforms in CJK,
  # you need to set a font installed in your server.
  #
  # This setting is not necessary in non CJK.
  #
  # Examples for Japanese:
  #   Windows:
  #     rmagick_font_path: C:\windows\fonts\msgothic.ttc
  #   Linux:
  #     rmagick_font_path: /usr/share/fonts/ipa-mincho/ipam.ttf
  #
   rmagick_font_path:

  # Maximum number of simultaneous AJAX uploads
  #max_concurrent_ajax_uploads: 2
  "/opt/redmine-3.1.0/log/"
  # Configure OpenIdAuthentication.store
  #
  # allowed values: :memory, :file, :memcache
  #openid_authentication_store: :memory

# specific configuration options for production environment
# that overrides the default ones
  production:

# specific configuration options for development environment
# that overrides the default ones
  development:"/opt/redmine-3.1.0/log/"
```

Thanks to Deepak's suggestion I added a "development" section in my database.yml but now I am getting this error:

```
[user@machinename redmine]$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 52 column 3
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:86:in `load_from_yaml'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:42:in `load'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:67:in `[]'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:24:in `<module:Thumbnail>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:21:in `<module:Redmine>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Output from @lightalloy's suggestion:

```
[user@machinename redmine]$ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 52 column 3
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:86:in `load_from_yaml'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:42:in `load'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:67:in `[]'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:24:in `<module:Thumbnail>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:21:in `<module:Redmine>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/thumbnail.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-3.1.0/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/XX_USERNAME_XX/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified` what's in your config/database.yml?

Comment: check if you have configuration for development env in database.yml

Comment: Added the config/db/yml files in the first post.

Comment: @LeviHen if those are the real passwords please change them while posting on Stack Overflow

Comment: Obviously we checked to see if we have the correct credentials, I just don't make a habbit of it posting those online ;)

Comment: What is the string `configuration.yml #      address: "example.com"` doing on line 52? Clearly, that's what is causing the problem. After you ensure that the Configuration.yml file is valid, you might need to run `rake db:create`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need to set up the production environment by your database.yml
So you need to specify it when you run rake db:migrate:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: added output to original post

Comment: line 52 in your   configuration.yml is strange:
'configuration.yml #      address: "example.com"'
It seems like you accidentally pasted 'configuration.yml' there. Try to remove it.

Comment: Yeah that looks like a whoopsie, corrected it and now it gives me this:
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 11 column 3

Comment: Re-check your whole configuration.yml
I think the lines after the 'default:' should be indented 2 spaces more.
Also check the end of the file - some lines don't look good (secret_token: 'rake output I generated before and copy-pasta'ed')

Comment: I replaced the generated key with that line for SOF ;)
I double checked all the lines and they all have 2 spaces and no tabs.
And this is the standard config file after installation, shouldn't it just work right out of the box or is that just my windows background assumption?

Comment: Well, you had random 'configuration.yml' string in one of the lines, that means that the file was somehow modified.
As for the indentation I don't mean tabs, but the fact that the lines starting from 'email_delivery' should be indented 2 spaces more than now - compare with the example: https://svn.redmine.org/redmine/trunk/config/configuration.yml.example

Comment: If I use (your) standard template I get this:
SyntaxError: /opt/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/configuration.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input

Comment: That was not real config. It was just an example for the indentation in the beginning of the file.
You should read the docs and format the file properly - and that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the configuration for development env in `config/database.yml`

If not please add the following entry in `config/database.yml`

```
# MYSQL

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: development_db
  host: localhost
  username: username
  password: password
  encoding: utf8

# # SQLite

# development:
#   adapter: sqlite3
#   database: db/development.sqlite3
#   pool: 5
#   timeout: 5000

# # Postgres

# development:
#   adapter: postgresql
#   encoding: unicode
#   database: development_db
#   pool: 5
#   username: username
#   password: password
```

Comment: I dont have anything like that in my config.yml but my database.yml does look a lot like that.

Comment: I am talking about `database.yml` only

Comment: just copy paste one setting and change the name from `production` to `development`

Comment: Yeah I added the database.yml and configuration.yml files to the original post.

Comment: and change the appropriate username and password values

Comment: change it in the file and try `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Obviously we checked to see if we have the correct credentials, I just don't make a habbit of it posting those online ;)